# how to get array of id for object array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

So here is object array in ruby

```
array = [{"login":"joseph","id":4,"url":"localhost/joe"},{"login":"billy","id":10,"url":"localhost/billy"}]
```

How to get that array is only contain ids so something like this,
[4, 10]

Comment: What's actually the problem?

Comment: The term _"object array"_ is redundant because in Ruby, all values are objects. You probably mean _"array of hashes"_.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_ids = array.map { |item| item[:id] }
```

when you use the syntax with `:` in your hash literal a symbol is always used as a key

If you want the hash to have string keys do this

```
array = [{"login" => "joseph", "id" => 4, "url" => "localhost/joe"}, {"login" => "billy","id" => 10,"url" => "localhost/billy"}]
```